# Polymer setting custom CSS property on inner element without using "!important"

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a custom element `x-foo` which I have defined a custom CSS property on to set the `background-color` called `--xbg`.

I use the element with elements of itself as children as so:

```
<x-foo class="outer">
  Outer
  <x-foo class="inner">
    Inner 1
  </x-foo>
</x-foo>
```

When I set `--xbg` on the outer, that value overrides the value of the inner element:

```
x-foo.outer {
  --xbg: orange;
}
x-foo.outer x-foo {
  --xbg: red;
  /* Doesn't work, have to use !important?!?!*/
}
```

I've used the inspector in Chrome and can see that the child definition  indeed is "lower" then the parent.

I have to "force" it to get higher with `!important`, which then has all sorts of other implications.

```
x-foo.outer x-foo {
  --xbg: red !important;
  /* Works */
}
```

Why is the child not overriding the parent property?

Here's a plunker for this with some more examples:
https://plnkr.co/edit/uZxg7G?p=preview (Only works in Chrome)

Simpler JSBin for other browsers:
http://jsbin.com/wuqobejeci/edit?html,output

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce this; the Plunkr isn't styling those elements... are you missing some library? Edit: Oh, it's Chrome-only.

Comment: I think example 2 should have a red `<x-foo class="inner">` like example3.

Comment: @TylerH wasn't suppose to be chrome only, but guess I'm missing something in plunker.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - what do you mean? I also think it should be red, but it isn't, that's the problem.. :)

Comment: That's what I tried to explain to @TylerH :D

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, haha ok :)

Comment: @TylerH Added a simpler Jsbin that works in other browsers

Comment: Re: all; I was referring to Polymer and web components not working in Firefox.

Comment: But it is working in FF if you use polyfills with "webcomponents-lite" as in jsbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to solve this is to say the style only applies to the class contentwrapper from that host down

```
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }

    :host > .contentwrapper {
      padding: 1em;
      background-color: var(--xbg, yellow);
    }

  </style>
```

Like that,

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/whoesv73/)

Comment: Yay! That works! But why? I thought we were living in shadow DOM that was leak-proof? i.e. I thought each instance was it's own host, so all styling only affected that host implicitly?

Comment: It's a strange one but because it was content it could be selected with the css selector ::content .contentwrapper which would still be picked up by .contentwrapper | If you'd have had it out side (so not content) it wouldn't have 'leaked'.

Comment: oops  ::content > .contentwrapper is what I meant to say

Comment: Not sure I follow completely, you mean that the inner `x-foo` could be accessed with `::content > .contentwrapper` on the outer, and therefor it leaks?

You think this behavior by design then?

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good at explaining myself, yes that's what I mean. I think it's probably a bug (or something they just live with). It's there so you can style h3 content (for example) you could say, ::content h3 {color:blue;} then and h3 tag in x-foo would be blue but it wouldn't leak outside of it. maybe this will help  https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/4a25m9p7/

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#styling-distributed-children-content

Comment: Nice fiddle, explains it better :)
Seen that Polymer guide page too many times already I think..hehe :D

Answer (score 1):

The element has lower priority than the class. Try

```
x-foo.outer {
  --xbg: orange;
}
x-foo.outer x-foo.inner {
  --xbg: red;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, added Example 4 to plunker, or do you think the `id`selector is interfering somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Thought this was worth trying just based on Andrew's answer above -- just using the host style alone seems to work:

```
<style>
  :host {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: var(--xbg, yellow);
  }
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6tzoacxr/